# How to convert from varbinary to char/varchar in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a field which is varbinary. It has already been populated. Now how do i convert varbinary to varchar so that I can use the data in the field for some other purpose. I use a MySQL version 5.10

Answer (score 46):

Late answer...

You can use CAST or CONVERT thus

```
CAST(foo AS CHAR(100))
CONVERT(foo, CHAR(100))
```

[Supported types (5.5) are](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html):

```
BINARY[(N)]
CHAR[(N)]
DATE
DATETIME
DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
SIGNED [INTEGER]
TIME
UNSIGNED [INTEGER]
```

You **can not** cast to varchar directly.
There is [an open MySQL bug from 2008](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34564) which no-one seems to care about and is damn annoying

Comment: @gbn, What's the default encoding used for the `CHAR` in `convert`? Also, now that Oracle has taken over MySQL, are people putting more attention into fixing the bug?

Comment: @Pacerier: sorry, I'm not active with MySQL nowadays,

Answer (score 29):

The MySQL syntax that worked for me in a similar scenario to this is:

```
select cast(binaryColumn as CHAR) from table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cast operation:

```
select cast(column_name as char)
  from table_name
```

Comment: You cannot case to varchar as per the above comments.

Comment: But you can use `char` as per other above comment.