# How to use binary data type in MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, bit

I am stuck somewhere and need your guidance, basically I am inserting multiple values to single `colomn` using `bit-wise operator OR(|)` and my table structure is like
[image] and I am inserting weekdays like `1 for sunday`, `2 from monday`, `4 for tuesday`, `8 for wednesday`, and so on separating by `pipe sign(|)` like for `sunday` and `monday` it will insert like `1|2` and so on but when it inserted to table it is showing like that [image]

So now I want to know how will I select and show the exact value that I have inserted and how to update it using `php(codeigniter)` and `mysql`?

I have used this query `select cast(column_name as varchar) from table_name` and it gives the result by sum all the decoded value like 5 for 1|4, 3 for 1|2, but now how can I convert it to the inserted type like 1|2 for 3 and 1|4 for 5 and so on...

Comment: try `SELECT CAST( week_days AS CHAR ) from table_name`

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873085/how-to-convert-from-varbinary-to-char-varchar-in-mysql

Comment: the question is why do you want to store multiple values, separated by `|` in a binary column type? Typically anytime you store separated values, whether by commas (csv), tabs, or even `|`, you should normalize your table, and be adding one-to-many rows instead

Comment: @Sean the client wants to store the values like this

Comment: @Vicky What have you tried?

Comment: @user3284463  i have tried this `select cast(column_name as varchar) from table_name` and it gives the result by sum all the decoded value like 5 for 1|4, 3 for 1|2, but now how can i convert it to like inserted type like 1|2 for 3 and 1|4 for 5

Comment: Client wants to store the values like this? Since when do clients deal with architectural and normalization issues? If the client wants data like that, you can still normalize your data set and deliver a string concatenated by `|`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$column&(1<<$day)
```

will be `0` if that day is not in column and `1<<$day` if that day is in column in php.

You don't need to use binary type. Tinyint unsigned is enough. You can insert like this

```
(1|2)
```

In php, to convert it to the format you want,

```
echo '(';
$sep=0;
for($a=1;$a<=$column;$a<<=1)
    if($column&$a){
        if($sep) echo '|';
        else $sep=1;
        echo $a;
    }
echo ')';
```

Comment: can u plzz give a brief description about it ??

Comment: when i am trying to insert like (1|2) in database with tinyint datatype, it is inserting 0 in column

Comment: @Vicky `insert into a(a) values((1|2));` worked fine for me. I got 3.