# Syntax problem when made slight change when using mysql from Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a (relatively) small Python app that uses mysql, where I am making a small change to a "select", which is causing a syntax error.  If I take the modified "select" and try it directly with mysql, it seems to work, and I've been staring at the code for a while, so I was hoping that someone can point out what the problem with the modified code is?

Here's a snippet with the original code:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="dlwpod01.xxx.com", user="cfssl_user", passwd=MYSQL_PASS, db="certdb_development")

#Create cursor to execute SQL query and store result set
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute("SELECT serial_number, expiry FROM certificates WHERE status='good'");

#Good certs only, check date logic here
row = curr.fetchone()
currentDate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Create an inner cursor to perform db modifications
innercurr = conn.cursor()
```

and here's the modified code:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="dlwpod01.xxx.com", user="cfssl_user", passwd=MYSQL_PASS, db="certdb_development")

#Create cursor to execute SQL query and store result set
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute("SELECT cast (serial_number as CHAR), expiry FROM certificates WHERE status='good'");

#Good certs only, check date logic here
row = curr.fetchone()
currentDate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Create an inner cursor to perform db modifications
innercurr = conn.cursor()
```

The line that I am trying to change is the line with the "curr.execute(...)", to cast the serial_number to a CHAR (see [How to convert from varbinary to char/varchar in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873085/how-to-convert-from-varbinary-to-char-varchar-in-mysql))

The error/traceback that I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/products/cfssl/cfssl_crl.py", line 40, in <module>
curr.execute("SELECT cast (serial_number as CHAR), expiry FROM certificates WHERE status='good'");
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 163, in execute
result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 321, in _query
conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 505, in query
self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 724, in _read_query_result
result.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1069, in read
first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 676, in _read_packet
packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 223, in raise_for_error
err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHAR), expiry FROM certificates WHERE status='good'' at line 1")
```

EDIT:  I'm not sure "Why?" but my question was closed because it was not reproducible.  Was that because the answer (as in the one comment that was made below) was so obvious?  If so, my apologies... as I said I had been staring at the code and just missed that :)...  Thanks, Jim

Comment: remove the space between cast ( . 'By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and the parenthesis following it' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html